# Homotopy pullback is right adjoint in the derived category

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, derived-categories, pullback

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a map of CW-complexes with continuous maps as morphisms.

How would one show that homotopy pullback $\mathcal D/Y → \mathcal D/X$ is right adjoint?

Here $\mathcal D$ is the derived category (edit, I mean the category of CW-complexes with continuous maps).

Comment: I imagine that by "the derived category" you mean the category in which objects are CW-complexes and morphisms are homotopy classes. Is there really a homotopy pullback functor $\mathcal D/Y\to \mathcal D/X$? I don't believe so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such functor $\mathcal D/Y\to \mathcal D/X$. It's clear what is meant to be on objects, but it is not well-defined on morphisms.

Let $f$ be the inclusion of a point $p$ into a circle $C$. Let $g$ and $h$ be the inclusions of two points, say $q$ and $r$, into $C$. Regard $g$ and $h$ as objects of $\mathcal D/C$. There is a unique isomorphism between them. The homotopy pullback of $g$ along $f$ is the space of paths from $p$ to $q$ in $C$. The homotopy pullback of $h$ along $f$ is the space of paths from $p$ to $r$ in $C$. What map is the isomorphism between $g$ and $h$ meant to give from the one homotopy pullback to the other?

Comment: It is worth pointing out though that there is such an adjoint pair of functors between the $\infty$-categories of spaces over $X$ and $Y$. Maybe that's what OP had in mind? In any case, the phrasing is confusing.

Comment: Yes. And you don't need infinity categories to discuss that. There is an adjunction between the derived categories (or homotopy categories) of $Top/X$ and $Top/Y$. The main point is that the category of objects over $X$ in the homotopy category is different from, and not as good as, the homotopy category of the category of objects over $X$.

Comment: Oh I see the problem. it should be the derived category of Spc/X

Comment: Ok I get it now. Thanks for your help